# adding integers from multiple lines in a file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file called names.txt that has information looking like this

```
900608999 Hunter Price 60 70
900708988 Rachel Reed  70 80
```

I need a bash script that reads the test scores from test 1 (4th column), so we would add Hunters 60 and Rachel's 70, find the average and print it. Then do the same for test 2 (70 and 80) I believe you have to use a for loop but I am having trouble piecing it together. What I have so far is the basic for loop layout I was planning on using that simply returns all pieces of the file in a unorganized manner.

```
    for x in $(cat names.txt)
    do
        echo $x
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do?

```
awk '{sum4 += $4; sum5 += $5} END {print sum4/NR, sum5/NR}' names.txt
```

Output:

```
65 75
```

Comment: This did work! one more question though, how can i get it to round? for instance if it was 70.667, I would want it round up to 71 instead of the decimal points.

Comment: Add half NR to the quotien: `(sum4 + NR / 2) / NR` and to get that as an integer in the output, use `printf("%d", (sum4 + NR / 2) / NR)`